# Python Loop not moving with a if statement inside

Tags: python

Why isnt this loop moving when I called the function?. When I called `getnumber([2,3,"no","rain",5,0])`, it only returns `[2]`. Thank you for anyone's help!

```
def getnumber(a):
    for x in a:
        if type(x)==int:
            return [x]
```

Comment: because you're breaking the loop and telling it to return when the loop encounters an item of type `int`, which happens to be be 2... what is the desired behavior? do you want all of the ints?

Comment: Apparently, you expect the function to return more than one value - either you need to collect the results before executing a `return` statement, or you should write a generator and use `yield` instead of `return`, so yo can then iterate over the results from the generator.

Comment: @bryan60 yes i was trying to get all the numbers from the list and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Because you called return as soon as you found your first result. If you called get_number with ['a', 3], it would return 3.

If what you want is to build a list of all numbers, what you need to do is place them in a list and return them at the end.

```
def getnumber(a):
    r = []
    for x in a:
        if type(x)==int:
            r.append(x)

    return r
```

This can also be simplified to a list-comprehension as:

```
def get_number(a)
   return [ value for value in a if type(value) == int ]
```

Comment: However why doesn't this step (r=[ ] & r.append(x)) needs to be written in the simplified version?

Comment: Have a look at [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), a very Pythonic way to create a list and usually better/faster than loops and appends.